# Recursive co-tree Generation algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, networkx, graph-theory

At **pg.7 on [>this article<](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.08517.pdf?fbclid=IwAR3O7OlyDed0m9GvNH_lewEf1VPQx1PXiOivd201w_9tnAI1p07Kh7I-r-I)** there is a recursive algorithm that explains the generation of a co-tree given the co-graph. Based on this article I am trying to implement it in python3 using the library **NetworkX** for the graph structures and the library **treelib** for the tree data structure.

In order to be precise, I have created exactly the same graph of the example (once again at pg.7 of the aforementioned article) and I have written the following function:

```
import networkx as nx
from treelib import tree

# Globals
tree = Tree()
CC   = 0

def generate_cotree(G,tree_pointer=None,complemented=None):
    print("----------------")
    global tree
    global CC

    def _getID():
        global CC
        CC += 1
        return CC

    string = "[{0}] Called for graph G = (V,E)\n V = {1} \n E = {2} \n".format(tree_pointer,G.nodes,G.edges)
    print(string)

    vertexes = list(G.nodes)
    edges    = list(G.edges)

    graph_components = [G.subgraph(c).copy() for c in nx.connected_components(G)]

    if len(vertexes) == 1:
        '''
            G(V,E) where |V| = 0 --> Trivial Cograph
        '''
        print("...Added leaf node!")
        tree.create_node(tag=vertexes[0],parent=tree_pointer)
        return 0

    elif len(edges) == 0: # Trivial Cograph
        '''
            G(V,E) where |E| = 0 --> Trivial Cograph
        '''
        for vertex in vertexes:
            tree.create_node(tag=vertex,parent=tree_pointer)
            print("...Added leaf node " + str(vertex) + "!")

        return 0

    else:

        if not nx.is_connected(G):
            
            '''
            Case A: The G(V,E) is a not connected graph --> Add a 0-node and call the 
                    generate_cotree(g) for every g ε connected_components(G)
            '''
   
            print("...Added 0-Node")

            id = _getID()
            tree.create_node(tag=0,identifier=id,parent=tree_pointer)
            tree_ptr = id # Increment the Tree Pointer

            for sub_graph in graph_components:

                generate_cotree(sub_graph,tree_pointer=tree_ptr)

        else:
            '''
            Case B: The G(V,E) is a connected graph --> Add a 1-node and call the 
                    generate_cotree(g) for every g ε connected_components(~G) where ~G is the complement of G
            '''

            print("...Added 1-Node")

            id = _getID()
            tree.create_node(tag=1,identifier=id,parent=tree_pointer)
            tree_ptr = id # Increment the Tree Pointer

            complement = nx.complement(G) # Get ~G
            
            comp_graph_components = [complement.subgraph(c).copy() for c in nx.connected_components(complement)]

            for subgraph in comp_graph_components:

                generate_cotree(subgraph,tree_pointer=tree_ptr)
```

The code for graph B for which I execute this test is the following:

```
B = nx.Graph()
B.clear()
B.add_node(1)
B.add_node(2)
B.add_node(3)
B.add_node(4)
B.add_node(5)
B.add_node(6)
B.add_node(7)
B.add_node(8)
B.add_edges_from([(2,4),(5,6),(6,7),(5,7),(3,7),(3,6)])

'''
-----
GRAPH:
------
      (1)    (2)-----(4)

      (8)        (3)  
                /   \
               /     \
             (6)-----(7)
               \      /
                \    /
                 (5)              

'''
```

The problem is that I am getting the wrong co-tree and although I can see what is going wrong here I am not sure how to fix it:

```
EXPECTED CO-TREE:

          (0-node)---------- 
          /  |  \          |
        (1) (8)  \         |
                (1-node)  (1-node)
                 /  |      /  |   \
              (2)  (4)   (6) (7)   (0-node)
                                   |   \
                                  (3)   (5)

RESULTING CO-TREE AFTER generate_cotree()

          (0-node)---------- 
          /  |  \          |
        (1) (8)  \         |
                (1-node)  (1-node)
                 /  |      /  |   \
              (2)  (4)   (6) (7)   (1-node)
                                   |   \
                                  (3)   (5)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on this topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured it out. (Ι think ^^)

When the code below gets executed:

```
    comp_graph_components = [complement.subgraph(c).copy() for c in nx.connected_components(complement)]

            for subgraph in comp_graph_components:

                generate_cotree(subgraph,tree_pointer=tree_ptr)
```

which is a snippet from "Case B" in the function, each connected component of the complementary graph ~G (if any) gets checked for its connectivity since the function is called for every one of them. Which is false but its **not** clear in the algorithm. Instead, for every connected component the connectivity of the graph ~G should be considered. This, is why I changed the code in the following manner:

```
def generate_cotree(G, tree_pointer=None, complemented=False):
    # print("----------------")
    global tree
    global CC

    # _getID() is no longer a nested function, I moved it outside of the function

    # string = "[{0}] Called for graph G = (V,E)\n V = {1} \n E = {2} \n".format(tree_pointer, G.nodes, G.edges)
    # print(string)

    vertices = list(G.nodes)
    edges = list(G.edges)

    if len(vertices) == 1:
        # print("...Added leaf node!")
        tree.create_node(tag=vertices[0], identifier=getID(), parent=tree_pointer)
        return 0

    elif len(edges) == 0:
        for vertex in vertices:
            tree.create_node(tag=vertex, identifier=getID(), parent=tree_pointer)
            # print("...Added leaf node " + str(vertex) + "!")
        return 0

    else:
        if not nx.is_connected(G):
            id = getID()
            if complemented:
                tree.create_node(tag=1, identifier=id, parent=tree_pointer)
                # print("create node -> 1")
            else:
                tree.create_node(tag=0, identifier=id, parent=tree_pointer)
                # print("create node -> 0")
            tree_ptr = id
            connected_subgraphs = [G.subgraph(c).copy() for c in nx.connected_components(G)]
            for i in range(0, len(connected_subgraphs)):
                generate_cotree(connected_subgraphs[i], tree_pointer=tree_ptr, complemented=complemented)

        else:
            id = getID()
            if complemented:
                tree.create_node(tag=0, identifier=id, parent=tree_pointer)
                # print("create node -> 0")
            else:
                tree.create_node(tag=1, identifier=id, parent=tree_pointer)
                # print("create node -> 1")
            tree_ptr = id
            complement = nx.complement(G)
            complemented_subgraphs = [complement.subgraph(c).copy() for c in nx.connected_components(complement)]
            for i in range(0, len(complemented_subgraphs)):
                generate_cotree(complemented_subgraphs[i], tree_pointer=tree_ptr, complemented=not complemented)
```